# Look for formatting ques in text and make elements out of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a text editor that uses ques in the text like `:strong:` to determine formatting. I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $document = $_GET["document"];
    $user = $_GET["user"];
    if ($user != nil) {
        $pass = $_GET["pass"];
    }
    $pass = $_GET["pass"];
    //$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "levimeredith", "levimorganx2");
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Text Editor</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,300italic,300,100italic,100,700,700italic,400italic,500,500italic|Kalam:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="universal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    function titleFocus() {
        $(".title").css("border", "1px solid #666666");
    }
    function titleBlur() {
        $(".title").css("border", "none");
    }
    $('.input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
        var inputString = $(".input").html();
        var inputArray = inputString.split(" ");
        var newInputArray = {};
        var onStrong = false;
        for (var i=0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            if (inputArray[i] == ":strong:") {
                if (onStrong == false) {
                    newInputArray[newInputArray.length] = "<strong>";
                    onStrong = true;
                } else if (onStrong == true) {
                    newInputArray[newInputArray.length] = "</strong>";
                    onStrong = false;
                }
            } else {
                newInputArray[newInputArray.length] = inputArray[i];
            }
        }
        var newInputString;
        for (var i=0; i < newInputArray.length; i++) {
            newInputString = newInputString + newInputArray[i];
            if (i != newInputArray.length - 1) {
                newInputString = newInputString + " ";
            }
        }
        $(".input").html(newInputString);
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Once DOM stuff is ready
    });
</script>
<body>
    <textarea class="title" onfocus="titleFocus()" onblur="titleBlur()">Untitled</textarea>
    <div class="toolbar">
        Testing
    </div>
    <div class="input written" contenteditable><strong>Testing </strong>Testing</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this just doesn't work. The console isnt showing any errors at all. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: why do you modify `newInputArray[newInputArray.length - 1]` instead of `newInputArray[i]`

Comment: On a `div` you need to use `$().html()` not `$().val()`

Comment: @trincot Ok, I've changed it to html instead of val and it still hasnt worked. Also, I changed `newInputArray[newInputArray.length - 1]q` to `newInputArray[newInputArray.length]` I use this because I want to add something to the table.

Comment: That sure will not work: you are just adding "<strong>" and "</strong>" elements in a new array, and turn that into a string. This would change an input like "bla :strong:bla:strong: bla" to "<strong></strong>". What use does that have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `$(..).val()` but `$(..).html()` when working with an (editable) `div`.

Also, the string manipulation you do, can be done much easier using regular expressions:

```
$('.input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    var inputString = $(".input").html();
    var newInputString= inputString.replace(
        /:strong:(.*?):strong:/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
    if (newInputString !== inputString) {
        console.log (newInputString);    
        $(".input").html(newInputString);
    }
});
```

Move your code to after the close of the `body` tag, so the document exists at the time you want to bind the above event handler. To be really safe, you should even move it into a `$(function () { });` construct, so the event handler is attached when the document is really loaded.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgqwanq9/) that demonstrates it.

Comment: Okay, I've done this on my side and it still doesnt work.

Comment: Check the fiddle, it works. If it doesn't work for you, it means you have some other code that breaks it. Could you post all your code in a fiddle as well and link to it in your question? That way we have all info needed to see what goes wrong.

Comment: Also, it is not helpful to just say "it doesn't" work. Do you get errors in the console? Do you debug the code with `console.log` to see which parts are executed?

Comment: I don't see anything in the console. Not even the new string. I've updated the code in the op.

Comment: Please show your original code, but everything, like the inclusion of jQuery, ... Without jQuery this code will not work, of course.

Comment: Okay, I've shown all the original code in the OP. However, replacing my JS with yours still doesnt fix my problem.

Comment: Ok, your problem is that the page is not loaded when you bind to the `div`. At that time it does not yet exist. Move your `script` tag with the code to after the close of the `body` tag.

Comment: Okay, this works, however when using backspace no matter how far I go back, after I've made a part of text strong I can never write anything not strong unless I use the mouse to navigate into a word not strong.

Comment: Indeed, making a rich text editor is not so easy. And you are only scratching the surface of the many problems still to uncover as you go on. It cannot be the purpose to now go on via these comments and try to make a rich text editor. There are some good widgets out there that do the job, and when you look at the many pages of code they represent, you'll know what I mean.